# Superellipse Stroustrup

Tags: c++

Exercise 13, from Chapter 12 of Stroustrup's Programming principles and practice using c++.

> A superellipse is a two-dimensional shape defined by the equation
>
> [image: |x/a|^m + |y/b|^n = 1; m, n > 0]
>
> Look up  *superellipse* on the web to get a better idea of what such
>   shapes look  like. Write a program that draws "starlike" patterns by
>   connecting points on  a superellipse. Take a, b, m, n, and N as
>   arguments. 
>   Select N points on the  superellipse defined by a, b, m,
>   and n. Make the points equally spaced for  some definition of
>   "equal" Connect each of those N points to one or more  other points
>   (if you like you can make the number of points connected to another
>   argument or just use N-1, i.e., all me orner points).

i have a vector that contains points with which i can build the superellipse
 i cant get the second part of exercise - how to find N-points lying on  superellipse to build stars?

thanks

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }
    Point() :x(0), y(0) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int sgn(double d) {

    if (d < 0)
        return -1;
    if (d == 0)
        return 0;
    if (d > 0)
        return 1;
    // exception
    error("sgn: something gone wrong\n");
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

vector<Point> superellipse(double a, double b, double m, double n, double precision = 0.01, int xCenter = 200, int yCenter = 200) {
    if (precision >= 1.00 || precision < 0.001)
        error ("use numbers from range [0.001 ; 1.00) for precision parametr\n");

    vector<Point> points;
    Point temp;
    Point P;
    for (double d = -1.0; d < 1.00; d += precision) {
        double t = d*M_PI;
        int x = pow((abs(cos(t))),2.0/m) * a * sgn(cos(t));
        int y = pow((abs(sin(t))),2.0/n) * b * sgn(sin(t));
        P = Point(x + xCenter, y + yCenter);
        if (P != temp) // ignore dublicates
            points.push_back(P);
        temp = P;
    }

    return points;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

1.scratch

```
vector<Point> superellipse (/*...*/) {
/* */   
        return points;
}
```

2.put

```
class Superellipse {
    std::vector<Point> _points;
    void draw_connected(const Point& A, const Point& B);           
  public:
    void draw_star(/* params */);
    Superellipse(/* params*/){
        /* initialize _points*/
    }
};
```

---

> i cant get the second part of exercise - how to find N-points lying on
>   superellipse to build stars?

???
You already have the points in your vector.

http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/programming_ch12.pdf

> if you like you can make the number of points connect to another
>   argument or just use N–1, i.e., all the other points

```
void Superellipse::draw_star (/* */){
    int N = _points.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
         for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) {
              draw_connected (_points[i], _points[j]);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code draws whole superellipse  http://codepad.org/wteEs2Rf
But I need an algorithm that would found the points that are the vertices of a regular N-polygon among all the points for which the figure is based.

Comment: No you don't. The exercise is: 'Make the points equally spaced for some definition of "equal"'. That does not imply the resulting star will have to be a regular polygon in an euclidean plane. And - aside of that - defining a suitable metric is a question of maths, not of programming.